# Jenkins Enable project-based security on a folder and assign permissions to a user remotely using python script

Tags: python, jenkins, groovy

I have a python script that creates a folder in Jenkins using `/createItem`.

I need to enable the project-based security on that newly created folder and also assign all the perms to a particular user using that python script. I have seen this sample code to perform similar actions: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Grant+Cancel+Permission+for+user+and+group+that+have+Build+permission that can be run in **Jenkins Script Console**, but is there a way to do this from my **python** script?

[image]
TIA

Comment: Which python library are you using? Or are you just using the APIs?

Comment: @ycr I am using Jenkins API. Can you suggest any Python library that would be helpful to do this?